# Wavelets for preconditioning in MATLAB

Tags: wavelets, condition-number

I have been trying to understand the Wavelet transform in order to use it as a precondioner for ill-conditioned linear problems of the form $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$.

I have come across [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c9c3/1a3db457c39aa64ce7b8edc4cf640df623af.pdf) that is attempting to do the aforementioned. The paper lays out an algorithm in which I must compute $\tilde{A} = RAR^T$ where $R$ is defined as:$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}H_0^N \\ H_1^N\end{bmatrix} ⊗ \begin{bmatrix}H_0^N \\ H_1^N\end{bmatrix}, \quad R = \begin{bmatrix}(G_0^N)^T \\ (G_1^N)^T\end{bmatrix}^T ⊗ \begin{bmatrix}(G_0^N)^T \\ (G_1^N)^T\end{bmatrix}^T,
$$
where in turn $H$ and $G$ are defined as:\begin{gather*}
H_i^{\frac{N}{2^m}} ≜ {\small\begin{bmatrix}
h_i[0] & h_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 1] & h_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 2] & h_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 3] & \cdots & \cdots & h_i[2] & h_i[1]\\
h_i[2] & h_i[1] & h_i[0] & h_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 1] & \cdots & \cdots & h_i[4] & h_i[3]\\
h_i[4] & h_i[3] & h_i[2] & h_i[1] & \cdots & \cdots & h_i[6] & h_i[5]\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
h[\frac{N}{2^m} - 2] & h[\frac{N}{2^m} - 3] & h[\frac{N}{2^m} - 4] & h[\frac{N}{2^m} - 5] & \cdots & \cdots & h_i[0] & h[\frac{N}{2^m} - 1]
\end{bmatrix}},\\
G_i^{\frac{N}{2^m}} ≜ {\small\begin{bmatrix}
g_i[0] & g_i[1] & g_i[2] & g_i[3] & \cdots & \cdots & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 2] & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 1]\\
g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 2] & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 1] & g_i[0] & g_i[1] & \cdots & \cdots & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 4] & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 3]\\
g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 4] & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 3] & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 2] & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 1] & \cdots & \cdots & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 6] & g_i[\frac{N}{2^m} - 5]\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
g_i[2] & g_i[3] & g_i[4] & g_i[5] & \cdots & \cdots & g_i[0] & g_i[1]
\end{bmatrix}^T}.
\end{gather*}

**My question is: how do I calculate $R$ in MATLAB in order to compute $\tilde{A} = RAR^{T}$? Is there a predefined function? I understand that MATLAB has `dwt` and `dwt2`, but these functions provide me with the results and not the matrix $R$.**